# Genymotion vitual devices are not shown in android studio

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, android-studio-2.1

[genymotion screenshot][1]

It seems the Genymotion [with virtual box] installed perfectly as well as the virtual devices.I have also installed the Genymotion plugin in my android studio(version 2.1).
[Genymotion plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JHM.png)

But the problem is, when I'm trying to run any app, the Genymotion devices are not shown in the emulators list. what is the problem. Please help me.
[emulators not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3asE.png)

Comment: Open a terminal and enter 'adb devices'. This command will show the Android devices connected to you environment. Please then copy paste the answer given by this command into your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to highlight one of those genymotion virtual devices and click that start button.  Wait for it to launch and load up, then try to run your app and it will launch the app inside of that genymotion vd.